# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'logout' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I keep getting this error:

> BankLayoutHeader.tsx:73 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'logout' of undefined
>       at BankLayoutHeader._this.handleLogout (BankLayoutHeader.tsx:73)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:201)
>       at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:466)
>       at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:488)
>       at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:586)
>       at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:597)
>       at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:567)

How can I solve this problem?

```
export interface IStateProps {
  authListBranch?: IAsyncData<void>;
}

interface IDispatchProps {
  authActions?: typeof AuthActions;
}

class BankLayoutHeader extends React.Component<
  IDispatchProps & IStateProps,
  {}
> {
  private handleLogout = () => {
    const { authActions } = this.props;
    authActions.logout().then((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  };

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={this.handleLogout}
        className="admin-layout-header-logout"
      >
        Logout
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Actions-> consts.ts

```
export const AuthActions = {
    LOGOUT: 'LOGOUT',
};
```

Actions-> index.ts

```
export function logout(): any {
  return (dispatch: any) =>
    dispatch({
      payload: AuthService.logout(),
      type: AuthActions.LOGOUT,
    });
}
```

Reducess-> index.ts

```
export const initialState: IAuthState = {
  logout: getInitialAsyncData<void>(),
};


export const logout = asyncItemReducerGenerator<void>(
  AuthActions.LOGOUT,
);

export const AuthReducers = combineReducers<IAuthState>({
  logout,
});
```

Services-> index.ts

```
logout(): Promise<any> {
  return postRequest<any, any>(
    `${BASE_URL}/${AUTH_BASE_ENDPOINT}/logout`
  );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

your `BankLayoutHeader` Component is not receiving the `authActions` as prop.

The first thing to do is to check if `authActions` exists before calling the `.logout()` method.

```
private handleLogout = () => {
  const { authActions } = this.props;
  authActions && authActions.logout().then((response: any) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
};
```

Next, I am assuming you are using Redux,

So, use the `connect` function to `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` according to your need.